# plink truncating commands

Tags: bash, putty, plink

I'm using plink.exe on WinXP to run some commands on Z/OS BASH. My commands are interspersed with echo commands so that I can parse the output and work out what is where. The first dozen or so commands run fine, but then one of them gets truncated.
For example:

```
echo :end_logdetail:
echo Job Name : TfmMigration
echo :jobinfo:
```

What happens:

```
user@host:/dev> echo :end_logdetail:
:end_logdetail:
user@host:/dev> echo Job Name : Tf
Job Name : Tf
user@host:/dev> echo :jobinfo:
:jobinfo:
```

I just checked where in the input file the error occurs, and it's exactly 4444 bytes in, on line 116 (so it's done 115 successful commands before it goes wrong). The command I'm using is:
Code:

plink -batch -pw xxxx user@host < "c:\dev\telnetcmd.txt" > "c:\dev\telnetout.txt"

The telnetcmd.txt is just a DOS text file with an "exit" command at the end.

Any idea why one of my commands is being truncated in this way?

*Update*: I don't get the problem if I pass the command file to plink with -m, only when I feed it in with the < operator.

Comment: what if you move the command that is on line 166 to earlier in the file. Does it still blow up (indicating a bad command format). If not does the new command at line ~116 blow up. I recall in past that DOS pipes and redirection where not very robust, blowing up at small sizes. Hard to believe that is the issue, but maybe you can disprove that before looking at other issues. Good luck.

Comment: If I change the script, it truncates in different places (I no longer have the script exactly as it was, as it is generated on the fly, I will try to save one and do some experimentation). Several commands are being truncated, at one point an echo is just truncated to "ec", this could be dangerous if "rm *.bak" were truncated to "rm *"! And that the script is generated, implies that it is not a format error. I've looked in a hex editor and there's nothing odd about the commands.

Comment: make a test script that is only 'echo 1; echo 2; echo ....n, ' see if it truncates at same place on multiple tests? Can you make a larger file not blowup when you take plink out of the picture? Are there plink options that control the size of the commands it can process? Probably all stuff you have thought of. Or search here for techniques to use `ssh` for remote command invocation. I'm still thinking DOS like pipe and redirection lack of robustness. Any XP people that can elminate that as an issue? Try the putty support group at putty.com (or whatever)? Good luck.

Comment: If I copy the script onto the Z/OS box, it does not truncate any commands, and plink is the only mechanism that I have to run commands in this manner from a file on the Windows machine. putty.com is a company that sells putty, and the PuTTY devs don't have forums other than for developers, not for end users. I've posted here, on unix.com, and on comp.terminals.

Comment: what about (from plink man page) `.... -m file   #read remote command(s) from file`

Answer (score 0):

As shellter points out, I should have been using the -m option. This does mean that (unlike the telnet solution that I was using) my commands do not show up in the output, and neither do the shell prompts, but I can manage without those.